# swift4.2でURLを指定してweb上にある音楽ファイルを再生したい。

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4

下記のサイトを参考にして、ローカルにある音楽ファイルを再生することができました。

https://i-app-tec.com/ios/avaudioplayer.html

次に、web上にある音楽ファイルを、
URL（例えば、https://example.com/data/sample.mp3 のようなもの）を指定して、再生しようとしています。

単に

```
let audioUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "https://example.com/data/sample.mp3")
```

のように変更しても、うまく動きませんでした。

どうすれば、再生できるのでしょうか？

環境は下記のとおりです。

```
swift:4.2
xcode:10.1
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: `URL.init(fileURLWithPath:)`はファイルパスを渡して`URL`を初期化するためのイニシャライザなので、`http://...`と言ったURL文字列は渡せません。URL文字列を渡す場合には`URL.init(string:)`などを使ってください。ただし正しい`URL`を渡せたとしても[`AVAudioPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer)はファイル上またはメモリ内の音楽データを再生するものでリモートサーバ上の音楽データの再生については保障されていません。「データをメモリ上にダウンロードして`AVAudioPlayer`を使う」か「[`AVPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer)を使う」などの対応が必要になります。

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます。AVPlayerを使ってみます。